# What happens if I bind a JQuery event that is already bound?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now, I'm spending a lot of development time trying to make sure that each event is bound only once. If I stop spending time to do this and bind the same function to the same event multiple times, what happens? Will JQuery rebind the event (and thus waste processing time) or will it ignore it?

Comment: if you only want to bind an event once... use `$('body').one('event', 'element', function(){});

Comment: You can test it out yourself; in my version of Firefox at least, it just uses all of them in the order you declared them.

Comment: But I can not say if it ignores binding if it is already bound

Comment: Can you please provide a few samples? Yes, binding the same handler to the same event to the same element multiple times will result in duplicate events.

Comment: When using proper event handlers, you can attach as many as you'd like, so adding the same event handler twice, even if the code is exactly the same, results in the callback being executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

From https://api.jquery.com/bind/

"As of jQuery 1.4.2 duplicate event handlers can be bound to an element instead of being discarded. This is useful when the event data feature is being used, or when other unique data resides in a closure around the event handler function."

But then you should also try this:
It is better to use the .on() event handler because you can do all your binding just once and even before the item you are binding exists. Makes it easier to keep track of all your event handlers.

https://api.jquery.com/on/